# Rails accessing object from string containing object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am attempting to access an object based on a string containing the object's name. The object is scoped (I am using cancan to ensure that users can only access records they are allowed to access). I have included some code below with where I have got to:

```
operation_type:string, one of %w(add sub mult div)
left_operand_object:string
left_operand:string
right_operand_object:string
right_operand:string


def result
    r = [access object using left_operand_object]
    k = [access object using right_operand_object]

    if operation_type == 'add'
        r.instance_variable_get('@'+left_operand) + k.instance_variable_get('@'+left_operand)
    elsif operation_type == 'sub'
        r.instance_variable_get('@'+left_operand) - k.instance_variable_get('@'+left_operand)
    ...
end
```

So, two questions:

- How can I complete the `r = [access object using left_operand_object]` line, to allow me to access the scoped object based on its name from the string `left_operand_object`?
- Will `instance_variable_get` work if `left_operand` is something like `customers.count` or would it only work without the count method?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly, `left_operand_object` would be something like `"Customer"`?

If so, you can use `left_operand_object.constantize` to get your `Customer` class.
Probably safer to run `left_operand_object.classify.constantize`, so `"row_entry"` would become `RowEntry`.

I'm not perfectly clear what your second question is about. If you want to call the `count` method, you could do `r.send(left_operand.to_sym)` (assuming `left_operand = "count").

If `left_operand` is something like "sales.count", this would not work. I don't know if there's an idiomatic way to do it, but `left_operand.split(".").inject(r) { |a, b| a.send b }` does the trick for this particular case.

---

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly - left_operand_object would be something like "customer". Thanks for the info, I'll look into using constantize - I assume this will assign the object to the r variable, as expected?

Comment: I think the second question was a little unclear - I am asking if I can use the count method inside instance_variable_get to return the count as an integer, but I think your answer has given me the direction I need to go - left_operand would be something like "sales.count" (assuming I was trying to use customer.sales.count).